# WinForm RichTextDocument Flow Document

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

So I know that there is a way do do the Flow Document in WPF. I'm looking for a way to do a FlowDocument in WinForm. Below is a snippet of code that I'm trying to get to work in WinForm and I know it works in WPF. Trying to port.

```
range = new TextRange(rtbPreview.Document.ContentStart, rtbPreview.Document.ContentEnd);
fstream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
range.Load(fstream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
fstream.Close()
```

It errors out on the `rtbPreview.Document` section. Target Framework: .NET 4.5

Comment: I think all you want is `rtbPreview.LoadFile(_fileName);`

Comment: Would that load the .xaml that's there?

Comment: You can't load a FlowDocument into a WinForm's RichTextBox.  You would have to use the ElementHost control and keep using the WPF RichTextBox control instead.

Comment: Would you possibly have am example? Just something I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

You can host a WPF control including XAML `RichTextBox` in your WinForms form according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742215%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

1. Add `System.Xaml` to "Reference"
2. Right click your project and select "Add"->"UserControl"
3. Select "User Control (WPF)"
4. Deploy a xaml `RichTextBox` on the container.
5. Build the project.
6. Open WinForms `Form` designer
7. Click "Toolbox" view
8. Select "{Your project name} WPF User Controls"
9. Deploy the user control created in the step 4.